# how to limit the users of my web service?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service; let's say that this web service does many calculations, it consumes a lot of memory resources. If my web services is call by 2 different clients, then the server will consume twice the resources. is it possible to limit my service to being used by one client, but not by using user authentication?

One idea that I have is to know when the service is being consumed, so if another user wants to use the service, it will receive a message that the service is been used by another user.

I know that one of the major goals of web services is to allow many users, and limiting the concurrent users is not a good idea. I am just curious if it is possible and how to do it, where can i find the documentation so i can learn the process.

Comment: Which platform/language?

Comment: @JureC. i am using the IIS, C# as my language

Comment: It's `MaxConcurrentCalls` parameter for WCF. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentcalls.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If this is a WCF based service you can achieve the desired result by looking at the Instancing and Concurrency options available.

[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx)